# .gitignore stopped working when I connected my repository to MongoDB

Tags: github, github-desktop

I started having this problem when I connected my React Javascript project to MongoDB. This is what my Github Desktop has looked like ever since then.

[image: link to screenshot]

I tried searching the error message, and the search results told me to add the `node_modules` folder to my `.gitignore`. So I looked at [my .gitignore](https://github.com/sumwun1/fireflyWeb/blob/main/.gitignore) and saw that `node_modules` was already there. I tried  restarting my computer, uninstalling and reinstalling Github Desktop, making sure my `.gitignore` was saved in ANSI encoding, and going into WSL and entering `git rm -r --cached .` and `git add .`. My `.gitignore` still does not work. Is there anything else that might help?

Comment: Changing your `.gitignore` might help, to `**/node_modules` see this - https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/8251

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is that I accidentally saved the .gitignore file in the wrong folder.